# How to Implement a cross-platform app with single version of HTML5 markup using Yii, 1140 grid and jQuery Mobile?

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, yii, media-queries, responsive-design

I am starting a new cross-platform project next month. I've developed a number of apps with responsive design and fluid layout using Yii Framework, 1140 Grid and jQuery UI.  The next project has a twist - we want to use 1140 grid for the desktop version of the app and jQuery Mobile for theming the mobile version. I do not yet have experience with jQuery mobile.

As I see it, there are two strategies available to me:

1. Implement the 1140 and jQuery Mobile versions of the site as separate themes in Yii. Serve the appropriate theme to the user based on which platform they are using.
2. Implement a single theme that uses media query to serve jQuery Mobile to mobile users and 1140 grid to non-mobile users.

The second option interests me greatly: it offers an opportunity to develop the HTML5 markup *once*. As jQuery Mobile relies on `data-role` attributes instead of the `class` attribute, it would seem to be possible to have a unified markup structure, which is much easier to maintain, but offers completely different UX based on the user's platform.

Does anyone in the StackOverflow community have experience with developing an application using the 2nd option above (with or without Yii) and could you comment on how you set this up and whether it was successful... or am I dreaming?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1)** If you implement Media Queries to create a responsive design, start with the desktop version and then in a Media Query define the mobile version. I would do this because a larger percent of mobile browsers support Media Queries than desktop browsers.

Here is a link to browser support for Media Queries, notice IE 6-8 are the only non-supported browsers: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-mediaqueries

Here are some great docs for Media Queries: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Media_queries

.

**2)** You will probably want to use different custom JavaScript for desktop/mobile sites, so be aware that you will want to detect what type of device it is in JavaScript the same way you setup your Media Query so the CSS and JS will match. You could do this by setting some CSS for a hidden element in a Media Query, then using jQuery, check if the hidden element has the properties set in the Media Query CSS:

CSS --

```
#hiddenElement {
    display    : none;
    visibility : visible;
}

@media all and (max-device-width: 720px) {
    #hiddenElement {
        visibility : hidden;
    }
}
```

JS --

```
$(function () {
    var desktop = true;
    if ($('#hiddenElement').css('visibility') === 'hidden') {
        desktop = false;
    }

    //now the `desktop` boolean variable is set to `true` for desktop browsers and `false` for mobile
});
```

.

**3)** jQuery Mobile allows you to declare widgets with `data-attributes` but once the HTML is initialized by jQuery Mobile, lots of classes and HTML structure are added. Here is some example markup from the documentation site for jQuery Mobile.

This:

```
<a href="index.html" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-l">My button</a>
```

Turns into this:

```
<a href="index.html" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-l" data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-inline="false" data-wrapperels="span" class="ui-btn ui-btn-up-c ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-up-undefined">
    <span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all ui-corner-top ui-corner-bottom">
        <span class="ui-btn-text">My button</span>
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-l ui-icon-shadow"></span>
    </span>
</a>
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for this guide. I can't upvote you as I don't have enough reputation yet, but I will give this a try soon.

Comment: @user1245460 You can still Accept the answer if it fixed your issue.

Comment: I would first like to see what other suggestions come up and also have a go at implementing this properly so that I can give some feedback to the community...